# Travis CI builds failing - Phantom JS timing out with Mocha

Tags: typescript, phantomjs, mocha.js, travis-ci

I'm using Travis CI to automate unit testing for a Typescript project. Everything runs fine locally, but on Travis the following error message pops up at the end:

```
Running "mocha:test" (mocha) task
Testing: Tests/tests.html
Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.
```

https://travis-ci.org/FullScreenShenanigans/ChangeLinr/builds/58349376

.travis.yml:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "0.12"

before_script: 
  npm install grunt grunt-cli grunt-contrib-copy grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-contrib-clean grunt-zip

script:
  grunt
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by moving to [grunt-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mocha%20grunt-mocha). The problem remains unsolved, but since grunt-mocha is specifically made for running mocha in grunt, it seems reasonable to use it.

Relevant commits:

- https://github.com/FullScreenShenanigans/FullScreenMario/commit/1796bc4076f3268658a2077b32f997c361e60127
- https://github.com/FullScreenShenanigans/FullScreenMario/commit/0321da7fb2a6aa90ecd5354fbe5e9acfcd85f6dd

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error on Travis.
This is my new, working .travis.yml:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '0.12'
before_script:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli bower
  - bower install
```

In my case, I have all the grunt packages (except `grunt-cli`) you have listed in your `.travis.yml` listed as `devDependencies` in my `package.json`. (I think that's preferable, so that those dependencies are only being tracked in one place.)

I also don't have your `script: grunt` section, but that's just because I'm invoking `grunt test` from my `package.json`, i.e.:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "grunt test"
},
```

Relevant excerpt from my bower.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "chai": "~2.3.0",
  "mocha": "~2.1.0"
},
```

For reasons I have yet to determine, I found that I would get those PhantomJS timeout errors with Mocha >=2.2.0 (I specifically tested 2.2.0 and 2.2.4), so I kept Mocha to 2.1.x.

In case it helps, [here's an actual commit](https://github.com/eddies/home-dashi/commit/1cbe21e33ebc6d68523c1a43edde3d08154e2312) that implements all of the above.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for the answer, though I ended up solving it differently. Not being able to keep up-to-date with Mocha versions would be a bit of a killer.